# why constructor is not getting call for second object in an array

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider this program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class sample
{
public:
    sample()
    {
        cout << "consructor called" << endl;
        throw 5;
    }
    void test()
    {
        cout << "Test function" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    sample *s = nullptr;

    try
    {
        s = new sample[5];
        cout << "allocated" << endl;
    }
    catch(bad_alloc& ba)
    {
        cout << ba.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (const int& f)
    {
        cout << "catcting exception";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think the flow will be like this.

```
1. Allocate the memory for 5 object.
2. call the constructor for each object one by one.
```

But here while calling the constructor, i'm throwing an exception, which is handled. My doubt is why constructor is not getting called for second objects onwards??

Comment: Once your constructor throw exception, your control will be shifted to catch block. This will call contructor first time and then go to exception handler.

Comment: after the `catch` block is executed, execution continues from after the `try...catch` sequence. It doesn't jump back up to where the `throw` was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object creation will be in sequence, it can't create all five objects in one go. When the first object gets created your constructor will get called and as it throws exception, it will move control to exception handler block.

You exception Handler will print the appropriate message and have graceful exit.

Try your test removing `throw 5;`

Answer (score 1):

The `new simple[5]` will allocate memory for the 5 `simple`s, and then begin constructing them one by one. Since the first one does a `throw 5`, the other 4 do not get constructed.